# Can a map have a non primitive key?

Tags: c++, dictionary

What I'm trying to know is can I declare a map having a non-primitive key like this?

```
map <Aluno, int> grades;
```

Where Aluno is an object. My teacher didn't know the answer so I ask you guys. Is it possible or will I have to use integers, string, etc.?

Comment: Yes it can. And there are plenty of SO questions concerning what must be in place for a user defined type to be used as key.

Comment: Too easy to test with a compiler.

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth it isn't *that* easy.

Comment: Since I had some problems using this kind of structure and my teacher pointed out that perhaps was because I was using a non primitive key.

Comment: Definitely a duplicate. Sorry.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't search correctly then.

Comment: @user3127568, you would probably do us a favor if you could delete this question and just read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417636/can-we-use-a-user-defined-class-for-the-key-in-a-stl-map) one instead.