# Understanding Map in C++ as a Java developer

Tags: java, c++, dictionary, equals, hashcode

in Java, we´ve got methods like hashCode() and equals() which are used by the map to identify each object. C++ doesn´t have such basic methods, each object implements by default.

How can a map now use custom objects as the key value?

Edit: No duplicate because it´s especially aiming towards those java specific interface methods, someone who has nothing done before with C++ would look for

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, a `std::map` in C++ is generally a red black tree, not a hash table. There is also a hash map in C++11 called `std::unordered_map`. By default it uses `operator<` to compare elements. You can also plug in a custom comparator which can compare using anything you want. This is done by using the optional 3rd template argument to `std::map`.

Answer (score 6):

C++ `std::map` is an ordered map, with requirements that mean that it is implemented as a self-balancing binary search tree (usually red-black tree). This means that the key types must have some kind of [strict weak ordering](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/StrictWeakOrdering.html), which can come in the form of a `less-than` operator, or as a user defined comparison functor.

There are plenty of SO posts on how to use an `std::map` with user-defined types as keys (see [one example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417636/can-we-use-a-user-defined-class-for-the-key-in-a-stl-map)).

C++11 has `std::unordered_map`, which is a hash table with different requirements on key types (specifically, a hashing function and equality comparison are required)

Answer (score 2):

Map in C++ is not HashMap, but rather an ordered map (implemented usually as a red-black tree). Entries are sorted by keys using the comparator function. In default implementation, keys must have `operator<` overloaded, but you can specify your own comparator function.

See here for C++ map info: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map

Answer (score 2):

Java's Hash map has time complexity of O(1). In C++, red-black tree based map has time complexity of O(logN).

CSLM is `hread-safe` ,`concurrent` and `TreeMap` is not .
CSLM was added in JDK 1.6

See  Docs:[Java equivalent of C++ std::map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2258449/java-equivalent-of-c-stdmap)

Answer (score 2):

std::map is a templated class. The key has to match a certain concept called strict weak ordering which guarantees:

- Keys are less-than-comparable (overload operator< or give the map a custom comparator)
- If element A is less than B, B can't be less than A
- If element A is less than B and B is less than C, then A is less than C

Here's an example with a custom type as key:

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>
struct Custom{ Custom(int c): c(c){} int c; };
bool operator< (Custom const &a, Custom const &b){ return a.c< b.c; }
int main(){ std::map<Custom, int> m; m[Custom(42)]= 42; std::cout<< m[Custom(42)]; }
```

That said, std::map is not the exact equivalent of Java's hash map. C++11 has `std::unordered_map` for that. With `unordered_map`, you can define your own std::hash template for your own type to persist your custom type as hash keys.

Answer (score 1):

C++ map is an ordered map, not a hash map, templated to use a boolean expression comp(a,b) to compare key values. The default is less which performs the (A < B) comparison, which in C++ can be overloaded by classes. Alternate maps can use different expressions.